# Background calls in Agora IO [React-Native iOS]

Tags: ios, react-native, voice, background-service, agora.io

I am trying to implement the functionality to keep Agora based voice calls alive even when the app goes in the background. I am using the React Native SDK by Agora for this and I want to implement this functionality specifically for iOS. I was able to do this for Android by using Foreground services. I don't know iOS development much nor do I know writing modules in Swift or Objective-C and bridging them to React Native. Any guides on how to achieve this can be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to enable the background mode VoIP in the app's Plist if you haven't already.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uibackgroundmodes

Edit: Use background mode `Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture`

Comment: this will eventually reject the ios app, saying that VOIP service is not used for this intended feature. either use the intended feature for voip or remove voip mode

Comment: apologies, updated my answer to the background mode that won't then get rejected